# Amazon SES generating HMCASHA256 signature

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried Amazon SES SDK and I was successful in sending Emails. But, while using the API reference to generate a API, I was not successful in generating the HMCA-SHA256 signature code. I have been getting this error. What would be the best way to verify if the key is generated correctly. I get the below as the REST trace.

> Could not find operation SendEmail for version 2010-12-01

Comment: A code snipped would be of use. Also I suspect you are not creating an API but a client for an API.

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of the AWS SDK?